# Preposition following 'ambitious'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In the following sentence, what will be the right preposition? 
He is ambitious ____ fame.

Comment: I would use "of" but it could well be archaic.

Comment: This is not a construction we'd normally use, so there's no "right" preposition. The two most obvious ones are *of* and *for*, but [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ambitious+for+fame%2Cambitious+of+fame&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cambitious%20for%20fame%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cambitious%20of%20fame%3B%2Cc0) shows they're both exceedingly rarely used. To confirm @michael.hor257k's comment, *of* appears to have been preferred in the 19th century.

Comment: I would use *for*, assuming that fame is the desired result of the ambition. However, generally one is said simply to be ambitious.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities depending on what you mean. That said, consider *for*.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#English) lists this as definition 10:

> In order to obtain or acquire.

Compare: He is hungry for fame. He strives for fame.

In this sense, *fame* is what *he* hopes to acquire. Why does he hope to acquire it? Because he is *ambitious*. So

> He is ambitious for fame.

Comment: Unfortunately, the combination "ambitious for" already has a different meaning, as in *"his mother was hard-working and ambitious for her four children"* (example sentence from NOAD).

Comment: Yes, just as *for* in general has well over ten distinct uses. Contextually, it should be clear how to understand "ambitious for <thing being sought>" as distinct from "ambitious for <people who one is working on behalf of>." See the example in Merriam-Webster def. 1b: "ambitious for power" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambitious)

Comment: Good point. You should add this to your answer.